# "It is not well" or "it is not good"?

Tags: adjectives, formality, register

Watching an old Dr. Who episode, one character said to another,

> "Highness, it is not **well** to think of the past, there is still the future to make."
>   <sub>("The Ribos Operation", 1978)</sub>

To my ear, this sounds wrong and should have been,

> "Highness, it is not **good** to think of the past, there is still the future to make."

Unfortunately, other than the way it sounds, I cannot determine the applicable grammar rules to know if I am correct.

Answer (score 7):

*It is well* is an old-fashioned and quite formal phrase meaning approximately *it is worthy of approval*, so *It is not well* means “You shouldn’t do that” or “That’s a bad idea”, but considerably politer.

*Well* was for many centuries used regularly as a predicate adjective in a number of senses, some of which last to this day, particularly the sense *in good health*:

> I hope you are well?
>   I've been sick but now I'm well.

The writers of historical novels and period dramas are fond of using now-obsolete expressions like *it is well* to lend an archaic flavour; and it is notable that the Ribos story is set in a culture vaguely reminiscent of the more backward parts of 18th- or 19th-century Eastern Europe.

Comment: Are you saying that both are correct, but that "good" is more colloquial?

Comment: @oldbrit Unless you want to sound like a character in a costume drama, yes.

Comment: What about context?

If the speaker means mental or physical health would be damaged by dwelling on the past, it would be "well", but if it's advice (in this case, about gaining power), it would be "good"?

How are you? I'm good. I've crossed off a lot of to-dos.

How are you? I'm well. I'm finally over the flu.

Comment: Given the context, I believe the speaker was talking about thinking of the past as an action which gets in the way of taking action to effect the future - So, "good" would correctly communicate the intended meaning.

Comment: @oldbrit I never said what it means, did I?! My apologies - I've added that at the beginning. ... And, again, yes, we would say *good* today.