# What does this ing part mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Such a portentous and mysterious monster roused all my curiosity. Then the wild and distant seas where he rolled his island bulk; the undeliverable, nameless perils of the whale; these, with all the attending marvels of a thousand Patagonian sights and sounds, helped to sway me to my wish. With other men, perhaps, such things would not have been inducements; but as for me, I am tormented with an everlasting itch for things remote. I love to sail forbidden seas, and land on barbarous coasts. **Not ignoring** what is good, I am quick to perceive a horror, and could still be social with it—would they let me—since it is **but well to be** on friendly terms with all the inmates of the place one lodges in.   [—Melville, *Moby-Dick*](http://americanliterature.com/author/herman-melville/book/moby-dick-or-the-whale/chapter-1-loomings)

And what does this "but well to be" mean?

I would like to hear from someone who has read this book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Not ignoring what is good**, I am quick to perceive a horror ...

The boldfaced part is a participle clause: a clause in which the role of verb is played by the non-finite *present participle* form.

When such clauses appear at the beginning of a sentence, their subject is taken to be the NP which is the subject of the following matrix (main) clause. Accordingly we parse this as:

> [While] I do not ignore what is good, I am quick to perceive a horror.

(*Quick* is used here in the sense “eager”; Ishmael has already told us that the ‘monster roused all my curiosity’.)

> It is **but well to be** on friendly terms ...

*But* is used here in the sense *merely, only, just*. *Well* is the old-fashioned adjectival use which was recently discussed [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/16094/32). We may paraphrase:

> It’s just a good idea to be on friendly terms ...

Comment: I thought this "but" was an intensifier.(from a dictionary) 2. Used as an intensive: Get out of here but fast!

Comment: birdman1234 I think that's a 20th-century usage, after Melville's time. Ishmael's justifying his odd willingness to "be social" with horror: "After all, it's only prudent" or "only good manners to be on friendly terms ..."

Comment: So is this but the same as "it's only fair to do that?"

Comment: @birdman Exactly! We rarely use *but* in that sense today, but it was once ordinary.

Comment: Don't misunderstand me; I'm sensitive to good things too; but I'm reelyreely turned on by horrid things.